# 4D Left Isoclinic Rotations as double rotations

Tags: matrices, rotations, quaternions, orthogonal-matrices

According to [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotations_in_4-dimensional_Euclidean_space) page, 4D left-isoclinic rotation matrices are double rotations of the same angle (and same sign). But in the same page, in the context of quaternions, it is mentioned that left-isoclinic matrices have the form:
$$R=\begin{bmatrix}a&-b&-c&-d \\ b&a&-d&c\\c&d&a&-b\\d&-c&b&a\end{bmatrix}$$ where $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $$a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2=1.$$ My question is, how can we view $R$ as a double rotation? I mean, how can we find the common angle? If two of $b,c,d$ are $0$ then it is easy to see. But what if this is not the case?

Comment: Undoubtedly you know that the eigenvalues of $R$ are $a\pm i\sqrt{b^2+c^2+d^2}$, both with multiplicity two. Need to think about a good way of describing the two rotated planes. The decomposition is not unique, I think? Which may explain why one is not suggested immediately except in the special cases that you listed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are always many ways to split $\Bbb{R}^4$ into a direct sum of two planes, stable under $R$ (and hence both rotated by the same angle).

The eigenvalues of $R$ are complex, $\lambda_{\pm}=a\pm i\sqrt{b^2+c^2+d^2}$, both with multiplicity two. Let $\vec{v}_1, \vec{v}_2\in\Bbb{C}^4$ be two linearly independent eigenvectors belonging to $\lambda_+$. Then their componentwise complex conjugates
$\vec{v}_1^*$ and $\vec{v}_2^*$ belong to $\lambda_-$. Consider the spaces
$$
T_j=\{z\vec{v}_j+z^*\vec{v}_j^*\mid z\in\Bbb{C}\},
$$
$j=1,2$. Clearly $T_1$ and $T_2$ are both subsets of $\Bbb{R}^4$ and $2$-dimensional vector spaces over $\Bbb{R}$. Furthermore
$$
R(z\vec{v}_j+z^*\vec{v}_j^*)=\lambda_+z\vec{v}_j+\lambda_-z^*\vec{v}_j^*\in T_j,
$$
so the two planes are stable under $R$.

Replacing $\vec{v}_1,\vec{v}_2$ with a different pair will produce different pairs of planes.

The common angle of rotation (assuming normalized to a unit quaternion) is $\arccos a$.

Comment: In light of echinodermata's simple argument this may be unnecessarily kludgy. Anyway, this approach generalizes to any rotation matrix $\in SO(4,\Bbb{R})$. The eigenvalues come in complex conjugate pairs, and we can find stable 2D subspaces following this recipe. Of course, in general the rotation angles on the two planes will be different.

Comment: Thank you for this. This is very helpful for me. Also, what if instead $R$ is right-isoclinic. What changes will happen?

Comment: I recommend using quaternions to find the angles and a pair of planes-of-rotation. It works just as easily for right-isoclinic as left-isoclinic!

Answer (score 2):

For this matrix, $a$ is the cosine of the rotation angle.

Proof sketch: First show that $R$ is an orthogonal matrix, so that $|Ru| = |u|$ for all $u$. Now recall that $u^T v =|u| |v|\cos\theta$ where $\theta$ angle between two vectors $u$ and $v$. So then, to compute the angle between $u$ and $Ru$, show that $u^T R u = a u^T u$.

Comment: The last identity is the key :-)

Answer (score 1):

Notice the first column! This is the matrix of left-multiplication-by-$(a+b\mathbf{i}+c\mathbf{j}+d\mathbf{k})$. We may write this quaternion in polar form as $ a+b\mathbf{i}+c\mathbf{j}+d\mathbf{k}=\exp(\theta\mathbf{u}) $.

Solving for the unknowns $\theta$ and $\mathbf{u}$ with Euler's formula yields

$$ \begin{cases} \cos\theta=a \\ \sin\theta=\sqrt{b^2+c^2+d^2} \end{cases}, 
\qquad \mathbf{u}=\frac{~~~~b\mathbf{i}+c\mathbf{j}+d\mathbf{k}}{\sqrt{b^2+c^2+d^2}}. $$

The angle $\theta$ is convex and $\mathbf{u}$ is a unit vector. If we extend $\{\mathbf{u}\}$ to an (appropriately oriented) orthonormal basis $\{\mathbf{u},\mathbf{v},\mathbf{w}\}$ for $\mathbb{R}^3$, then $\{1,\mathbf{u},\mathbf{v},\mathbf{w}\}$ is an orthonormal basis for $\mathbb{H}$ with the same orientation and multiplication table as $\{1,\mathbf{i},\mathbf{j},\mathbf{k}\}$.

With respect to *this* basis, the transformation acts as a rotation by $\theta$ in the oriented $1\mathbf{u}$-plane and its orthogonal complement, the oriented $\mathbf{vw}$-plane. (*Exercise*.)

There is more than one way to choose a pair of oriented, orthogonal, stable planes. The stable planes for $\exp(\theta\mathbf{u})$ are the same as for those of multiplying-by-$\mathbf{u}$. Multiplying by $\mathbf{u}$ is a complex structure on $\mathbb{H}$ making it a left complex vector space, so the stable planes are precisely the 1D complex subspaces! This forms the complex projective line $\mathbb{CP}^1\simeq S^2$, diffeomorphic to the Riemann sphere by stereographic projection.

(The space of *all* oriented 2D planes in 4D real space is the real Grassmanian $\mathrm{Gr}_2\mathbb{R}^4\simeq S^2\times S^2$, which can be shown in a couple ways using quaternions too.)